# Bang Notation and Dot Notation in VBA and MS-Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, vb6, notation

While perusing an application that I'm [documenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916319/documenting-a-access-application-for-developers), I've run across some examples of bang notation in accessing object properties/methods, etc. and in other places they use dot notation for what seems like the same purpose.

Is there a difference or preference to using one or the other? Some simple googling only reveals limited information on the subject with some people actually using it in opposite cases. Perhaps there is a coding standards section from MS somewhere that indicates the method of madness?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Despite the (formerly) accepted answer to this question, the bang is not in fact a member or collection access operator. It does one simple and specific thing: **The bang operator provides late-bound access to the default member of an object, by passing the literal name following the bang operator as a string argument to that default member.**

That's it. The object doesn't have to be a collection. It doesn't have to have a method or property called `Item`. All it needs is a `Property Get` or `Function` which can accept a string as the first argument.

For much more detail and proof, see my blog post discussing this: [**The Bang! (Exclamation Operator) in VBA**](https://web.archive.org/web/20180326080215/http://bytecomb.com/the-bang-exclamation-operator-in-vba/)

Comment: +1 Nice one, Joshua. Your blog post is a very good distillation of knowledge about the bang operator. I've had to find out this the hard way since the MS documentation is so bad on this subject. I wish I had read all this 15 years ago!

Comment: I don't work in VBA/MS Access any more so I can't really confirm your findings... how sure are you? Do you want this to be the accepted answer?

Comment: @Nitrodist I'm very sure. I work with VBA every day. My blog post includes some proof-of-concept code as well. As to whether it should be the accepted answer...only you can decide that :)

Comment: @Nitrodist: I'm also very sure that Joshua is right. My answer makes the same point without saying it as clearly ;-). See the footnote in my answer for example. The first sentence in my answer really wasn't the best choice of wording - I was stating a common use case but making it seem like I was defining the bang operator's purpose/behavior, which wasn't intended. Still, my answer only _suggests_ that it invokes the object's default member, without actually saying it, so this answer is definitely more to the point than mine was.

Comment: I always wondered "how could an extension change the rules of the language" when working with VB4.

Comment: So would I be correct in saying that the only advantage of using the bang operator is to save typing (and arguably improve readability)? Are there any disadvantages such as a minor performance hit versus the dot operator?

Answer (score 34):

The bang operator (`!`) is shorthand for accessing members of a `Collection` or other enumerable object, such as the `Fields` property of an `ADODB.Recordset`.

For example, you can create a `Collection` and add a few keyed items to it:

```
Dim coll As Collection
Set coll = New Collection

coll.Add "First Item", "Item1"
coll.Add "Second Item", "Item2"
coll.Add "Third  Item", "Item3"
```

You can access an item in this collection by its key in three ways:

1. `coll.Item("Item2")`
   This is the most explicit form.
2. `coll("Item2")`
   This works because `Item` is the default method of the `Collection` class, so you can omit it.
3. `coll!Item2`
   This is short-hand for both of the above forms. At run-time, VB6 takes the text after the bang and passes it as a parameter to the `Item` method.

People seem to make this more complicated than it should be, which is why it's hard to find a straightforward explanation. Usually the complications or "reasons not to use the bang operator" stem from a misunderstanding of how simple it actually is. When someone has a problem with the bang operator, they tend to blame it instead of the real cause of the problem they are having, which is often more subtle.

For example, some people recommend not using the bang operator to access controls on a form. Thus, `Me.txtPhone` is preferred over `Me!txtPhone`. The "reason" this is seen as bad is that `Me.txtPhone` will be checked at compile-time for correctness, but `Me!txtPhone` won't.

In the first case, if you mistype the code as `Me.txtFone` and there is no control with that name, your code won't compile. In the second case, if you wrote `Me!txtFone`, you won't get a compile error. Instead, your code will blow up with a run-time error if it reaches the line of code that used `Me!txtFone`.

The problem with the argument against the bang operator is that this problem has nothing to do with the bang operator itself. It's behaving exactly the way it's supposed to.

When you add a control to a form, VB automatically adds a property to your form with the same name as the control you added. This property is part of the form's class, so the compiler can check for typos at compile-time if you access controls using the dot (".") operator (and you can access them using the dot operator precisely because VB created a named control property for you).

Since `Me!ControlName` is actually short-hand for `Me.Controls("ControlName")`<sup>1</sup>, it should not be suprising that you don't get any compile-time checks against mistyping the control name.

Put another way, if the bang operator is "bad" and the dot operator is "good", then you might think

```
Me.Controls("ControlName")
```

is better than

```
Me!ControlName
```

because the first version uses a dot, but in this case, the dot isn't any better at all, since you are still accessing the control name via a parameter. It's only "better" when there is an alternative way to write the code such that you will get compile-time checking. This happens to be the case with controls due to VB creating properties for each control for you, and this is why `Me.ControlName` is sometimes recommended over `Me!ControlName`.

---

1. I had originally stated that the `Controls` property was the default property of the `Form` class, but David pointed out in the comments that `Controls` isn't the default property of `Form`. The actual default property returns a collection that *includes* the contents of `Me.Controls`, which is why the bang short-hand still works.

Comment: Me.Controls is *not* the default "property" of the form object. The default *collection* for Me in a form or report is a union of the Controls and Fields collections. In as standalone class module, there is no default collection. Otherwise, and excellent answer that recapitulates an answer I posted a short while ago that I'm too lazy to look up!

Comment: @David: Sorry about that, I was thinking VB6 when I posted my answer, where the `Form` class doesn't have a `Fields` collection. I'll edit my answer to clarify. But now that you mention it, technically `Controls` isn't the default proeperty of `Form` in VB6 either: there is a hidden property called `_Default` that is listed as the default member of the class. Not sure if it is a union of multiple collections in VB6 or if it simply returns `Controls`. Good catch though. Now you've got me wanting to solve this mystery :-)

Comment: And coll.Item("Item2") isn't always the full story either. In most contexts you really mean coll.Item("Item2").Value, however in some places where an object reference is acceptable the object's default property (.Value) won't be selected. This can lead to hard to find errors, but it is rare. Note that this is not a failing of the ! syntax itself however.

Comment: @Bob: I considered adding that as another example where the bang operator is sometimes incorrectly blamed. I've seen a few times where someone suggests using `rs.Fields("ColumnName").Value` because `rs!ColumnName` "doesn't always work", but as you point out, any problems are due to not being explicit about using the `Value` property, in those situations where it does actually make a difference. `rs!ColumnName.Value` would have just as easily solved the problem, so  just another case where the blame is misplaced, and the real issue is how and when VB6 evaluates default properties.

Comment: I'm not sure if adding .Value will always work. Starting with A2000, there's been a disconnect between the form/report and the underlying recordsource, and this is reflected in the need to have a control with a controlsource for any field that you refer to in code. That is, if MyField is in the recordsource, but there is no control with it as ControlSource, referring to it in code is unreliable, not because of . or ! or .Value, but because MS has mucked up the relationship between the form/report and its Fields collection.

Comment: Although the accepted answer has been changed to the other - fine too - I prefer your examples and "case construction " playing as devil's advocate; it is more illuminating.

Comment: I always use `tabelle![myFeld]` with corner brackets because otherwise I get an error.

Answer (score 6):

Couple gotchas to serve as addenda to the two exceptional answers already posted:

**Accessing recordset fields in forms vs. reports**
The default item of Form objects in Access is a union of the form's Controls collection and the form recordset's Fields collection.  If the name of a control conflicts with the name of a field, I'm not sure which object is actually returned.  Since the default property of both a field and a control is their `.Value`, it's often a "distinction without a difference."  In other words, one normally doesn't care which it is because the values of the field and control are often the same.

*Beware of naming conflicts!*
This situation is exacerbated by Access's Form and Report designer defaulting to naming bound controls the same as the recordset field to which they are bound.  I've personally adopted the convention of renaming controls with their control type prefix (e.g., `tbLastName` for the text box bound to the *LastName* field).

*Report recordset fields aren't there!*
I said earlier the Form object's default item is a collection of Controls and Fields.  However, the Report object's default item is only its collection of Controls.  So if one wants to refer to a recordset field using the bang operator, one needs to include that field as the source for a (hidden, if desired) bound control.

**Beware conflicts with explicit form/report properties**
When one adds controls to a form or report, Access automatically creates properties that refer to these controls.  For example, a control named `tbLastName` would be available from a form's code module by referring to `Me.tbLastName`.  However, Access will not create such a property if it conflicts with an existing form or report property.  For example, assume one adds a control named Pages.  Referring to `Me.Pages` in the form's code module will return the form's *Pages* property, not the control named "Pages".

In this example, one could access the "Pages" control explicitly using `Me.Controls("Pages")` or implicitly using the bang operator, `Me!Pages`.  Be aware, though, that using the bang operator means that Access might instead return a field named "Pages" if one exists in the form's recordset.

**What about .Value?**
Though not explicitly mentioned in the question, this topic came up in the above comments.  The default *property* for Field objects and most "data-bindable"¹ Control objects is `.Value`.  Since this is the default property, VBA will implicitly return the `.Value` property's value when it does not make sense to return the object itself.  Thus, it's common practice to do this...

```
Dim EmployeeLastName As String
EmployeeLastName = Me.tbLastName
```

...instead of this...

```
EmployeeLastName = Me.tbLastName.Value
```

The above two statements produce identical results because `EmployeeLastName` is a string.

**Beware the subtle .Value bug when keying dictionaries**
There are some cases where this convention can cause subtle bugs.  The most notable--and, if memory serves, only--one I've actually run into in practice is when using the value of a Field/Control as a Dictionary key.

```
Set EmployeePhoneNums = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Me.tbLastName.Value = "Jones"
EmployeePhoneNums.Add Key:=Me.tbLastName, Item:="555-1234"
Me.tbLastName.Value = "Smith"
EmployeePhoneNums.Add Key:=Me.tbLastName, Item:="555-6789"
```

One would likely expect that the above code creates two entries in the `EmployeePhoneNums` dictionary.  Instead, it throws an error on the last line because we are trying to add a duplicate key.  That is, the `tbLastName` Control object itself is the key, not the value of the control.  In this context, the control's value does not even matter.

In fact, I expect that the object's memory address (`ObjPtr(Me.tbLastName)`) is likely what's being used behind the scenes to index the dictionary.  I did a quick test that seems to bear this out.

```
'Standard module:
Public testDict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Sub QuickTest()
    Dim key As Variant
    For Each key In testDict.Keys
        Debug.Print ObjPtr(key), testDict.Item(key)
    Next key
End Sub

'Form module:
Private Sub Form_Current()
    testDict(Me.tbLastName) = Me.tbLastName.Value
    Debug.Print ObjPtr(Me.tbLastName); "..."; Me.tbLastName
End Sub
```

When running the above code, exactly one dictionary item is added each time the form is closed and re-opened.  Moving from record to record (and thus causing multiple calls to the Form_Current routine) does not add new dictionary items, because it is the Control object itself indexing the dictionary, and not the Control's value.

**My personal recommendations/coding conventions**
Over the years, I've adopted the following practices, YMMV:

- Prefix Form/Report control names with control type indicators (e.g., `tbTextBox`, `lblLabel`, etc.)
- Refer to Form/Report controls in code using `Me.` notation (e.g., `Me.tbLastName`)
- Avoid creating table/query fields with [problematic names](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html) in the first place
- Use `Me!` notation when there are conflicts, such as with legacy applications (e.g., `Me!Pages`)
- Include hidden report controls to gain access to report Recordset field values
- Explicitly include `.Value` only when the situation warrants the added verbosity (e.g., Dictionary keys)

---

¹ *What's a "data-bindable" control?*
*Basically, a control with a `ControlSource` property, such as a TextBox or ComboBox.  A non-bindable control would be something like a Label or CommandButton.  The default property of both a TextBox and ComboBox is `.Value`; Labels and CommandButtons have no default property.*

Comment: I wish I had known all this points years ago when I heavily used Access... had to discover them the hard way. The funny thing about is that it's [official name](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/2003/07/15/dictionary-lookup-operator/) seems to be  dictionary lookup operator, just the example faulty case above :)