# What does "!" mean in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

Can somebody please tell me what the "!" means in line 5 of the following?

```
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("zTableFields", , dbAppendOnly)
rst!TableName = "Brad"
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bang Notation and Dot Notation in VBA and MS-Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923957/bang-notation-and-dot-notation-in-vba-and-ms-access)

Answer (score 1):

It is the delineator between the table or query name, and the field/column name.

These are identical:

```
    rst.Fields.Item(TableName).value = "Brad"
    rst.Fields(TableName) = "Brad"
    rst(TableName) = "Brad"
```

Comment: It is called the "bang operator."

Comment: Read this for an extensive explanation. http://bytecomb.com/the-bang-exclamation-operator-in-vba/

Comment: You forgot the `!` example.