# Referencing Controls in Subforms

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am having trouble determining exactly why the examples below are behaving the way they are.

**Works:**

```vb
Debug.Print Forms!Form1![Subform1]!control1
```

**Doesn't Work:**

```vb
Debug.Print Forms!Form1![Subform1].control1
```

**With Error:**

> Run-time error '438':
>   Object doesn't support this property or method

At first glance I just assume `.control1` is accessing a property of `Subform1` instead of the control itself so it makes sense why there would be an error.

Yet that reasoning doesn't seem to apply when using these to examples:

```vb
Debug.Print Forms!Form1![Subform1].Form.control1 
Debug.Print Forms!Form1!Subform1.Form.control1
```

**Screenshots of Results:**

[image: With Square Braces] 
[image: Without Square Braces]

To me these examples also look like I am accessing the a `.CHAT_MESSAGE_ID` property of the `Chat`'s form object, yet I get no error message and they work fine.

Why do these two examples work yet `Debug.Print Forms!Form1![Subform1].control1` doesn't?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923957/bang-notation-and-dot-notation-in-vba-and-ms-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many situations, an Access *form object* lets you access its controls and record source fields as if they are *properties* of the form.  That means you can employ Intellisense when you're editing VBA code within that form, so you can refer to the value of a control named *control1* with `Me.control1` or `Me.control1.Value`

That feature is also why `Debug.Print Forms!Form1!Subform1.Form.control1` *can* work.  However `Debug.Print Forms!Form1!Subform1.control1` fails because *Subform1* is a control, not a *form object*, and it does not include a property named *control1*.  (That is what the error message complains about.)

The situation can get more complicated if your subform's `SourceObject` is a table or query instead of an actual form object.  I haven't worked through the details with those variations myself, but I suggest you look into them if you really want to use the *SubformControl.Form.property* pattern.

I just use something like `Forms!Form1!Subform1!control1`, which is less confusing to me.

Comment: This line: `fails because Subform1 is a control, not a form object, and it does not include a property named control1.` was definitely a moment of clarity.   Which also explains why saying `.Form` sort of "casts" the control as a form and then it behaves "normally" again.

Comment: Good, I struggled with that.  ;-)  RE the last part of your comment, I would say `.Form` refers to the form object which is contained within the subform control.  That form object supports a property named *control1* but the subform *control* does not.

Answer (score 1):

The bang (!) operator accesses default properties and objects in collections.
Obviously `Subform.Form` is the default property of the `Subform` control and the `Controls` collection is the default property of the `Form` class. Therefore you can access controls on the subform with `Subform!ControlName`. If, however, you say `Subform.ControlName` you specifically try to access a property named "ControlName" of the `Subform` control. And that one does not exist.

The bank (!) operator searches for a matching object. The dot (.) operator assumes that an existing property is referenced directly.