# Difference between rs!field and rs.fields("field")

Tags: sql, vba, sql-server-2008

I have a question about preferences.
I have used and seen used both of these examples and was wondering if one is better/faster/preferred over the other...

Using SQL Server 2008
(RS = RecordSet)

```
RS!field
```

vs

```
RS.Fields("Field")
```

The first is shorter, quicker to type, but is there any advantage to one or the other?

Comment: This is ADO.NET right?

Comment: Did I get the wrong forum?

Comment: Not the wrong forum but you gave the wrong tags instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are equivalent in VB.  From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxda45fy.aspx):

> Use the `!` operator only on a class or interface as a dictionary access operator. The class or interface must have a default property that accepts a single `String` argument. The identifier immediately following the `!` operator becomes the argument value passed to the default property as a string.

Since `Fields` is the "default" property for `Recordset` and `Item` is the default property for `Fields`,

```
RS!field
```

is compiled to

```
RS.Fields("field")
```

which is technically

```
RS.Fields.Item("field")
```

Note that you can also do

```
RS("field")
```

> is one better/faster/preferred over the other?

Faster? No.  Preferred? Well the latter usage is more consistent with other .NET languages, so it may be preferred in larger circles because of that.

Comment: @Ben [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15958981/1081897) and the linked article within seem to indicate otherwise.  I'm no VBA expert by any means, but I think we're just in a semantic argument which doesn't change the heart of the answer that the two syntaxes are equivalent.

Comment: But does it call `Collect` because that's the _default_ property (which is implemented by using the special `DISPID_COLLECT` attribute)?  Or do _all_ classes that allow `!` have a `Collect` property?  I can't find any official MS documentation that confirms either statement - only forums.  But I still stand by the answer that they are equivalent, even if the actual mechanics of _why_ may be different.

Comment: Correction again: I just tried it in VBA and I was wrong. /hate it when that happens.