# VBA for Access apply filter in separate form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I'm working on a database in Access 2013 and I want to use one form to apply a filter to another. The form in question is called Advanced Search and I want it to use keywords input into text boxes to apply a filter onto a split form called FormA. Whenever I click the search button, I receive "run time error 424: Object required".

```
Private Sub Search_Click() 'Applies a filter based on search Criteria
    Forms!FormA.Filter = _
    "Field1 Like '*" & SearchBox.Value & "*' And Field2 Like '*" & SearchBox.Value & "*'"
    Forms!FormA.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

I feel as though I'm messing something up with the reference to FormA. Any Ideas?

Comment: Try turning filter on, add this line after: `Forms!FormA.FilterOn = True`

Comment: Forgot to copy that line in, though you're definitely correct as I'll need that to make it work in the end. Still get the same run time error when its there.

Answer (score 1):

The *"object required"* error is caused by `SearchBox.Value`.  Access does not find a control named `SearchBox` in the form (*Advanced Search*) which contains your `Search` command button.

After you find the correct name, I suggest you build your `Filter` string like this ...

```vb
Dim strFilter As String
strFilter = "Field1 Like '*" & Me![YourSearchBoxNameHere].Value & _
    "*' And Field2 Like '*" & Me![YourSearchBoxNameHere].Value & "*'"
Debug.Print strFilter '<- inspect this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
```

Then apply the `Filter` ...

```vb
Forms!FormA.Filter = strFilter
Forms!FormA.FilterOn = True
```

Also include `Option Explicit` in the Declarations sections of all your code modules.  And then run Debug->Compile from the VB Editor's main menu.  Fix anything the compiler complains about, and compile again.  Repeat until no more compile errors.

Comment: Thank you! My tired eyes missed missed the obvious mistakes. I even found a few naming errors elsewhere.

Comment: You're welcome.  In the VB Editor, choose Tools -> Options.  Then on the Editor tab of that Options dialog, place a checkmark next to Require Variable Declaration.  That setting will cause `Option Explicit` to be included in any *new* modules you create.  But it is not applied retroactively to existing modules.

Comment: Also, what is the reasoning for using the exclamation mark instead of a period when referencing objects?

Comment: See [Bang Notation and Dot Notation in VBA and MS-Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923957/bang-notation-and-dot-notation-in-vba-and-ms-access)

Comment: Thanks again Hans!