# What does it mean if a number is written in square brackets like [5]

Tags: vba

I am working on an legacy VBA/Excel app and stumbled over some lines of code where a long string (read from a file) is cut into pieces. Those lines look like this:

```
 Range("E16").Value = Mid(line, 49, [6])
```

Obviously, writing `[6]` means taking 6 characters, but I never saw this syntax to put square brackets around a number.

I did some tests and found out that putting those square brackets doesn't do any obvious to the number

```
Dim x As Double
x = 5.1
Debug.Print [2], [3.1], [-5], x
Debug.Print [3.1] * [x] * [-5]

>>  2             3.1          -5             5.1 
>> -79.05
```

So, no truncation, no rounding, no abs-value.
I did some more tests to check if it does some magic similar to putting parentheses around a variable to prevent modifying a value that is passed by reference, but that's not the case:

```
    x = 5.1: test2 x: Debug.Print x
    x = 5.1: test2 (x): Debug.Print x
    x = 5.1: test2 [x]: Debug.Print x

Sub test2(ByRef y As Double)
    y = y * 2
End Sub

>> 10.2 
>> 5.1
>> 10.2
```

Surprised that the compiler even accepts this syntax: What is the meaning of using those brackets?

Comment: `[]` are shorthand for `Application.Evaluate()`

Comment: @ScottCraner It actually depends on the context.  They're also used for foreign identifiers.

Comment: @Comintern okay, time for me to learn something, what are foreign identifiers?

Comment: @ScottCraner: So easy - when you know where to look. Thanks. If you put this as answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199603.aspx Special Identifier Forms

Comment: `[]` can also be used when accessing a table's column, such as `Range("Table[Col1]")`

Comment: @Mistella no, that's purely Excel range reference syntax, not VBA.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Square brackets in VBA/VB6 are used for accessing "foreign identifiers", i.e. identifiers that would otherwise not be legal. For example:

```
Public Enum Foo
    Some
    Thing
    [Some Thing] ' please don't do this
End Enum
```

And hidden members whose name begins with an underscore:

```
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = myCollection.[_NewEnum]
End Property
```

However in the context of the code in this question, the square brackets are, [as Scott indicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54579404/what-does-it-mean-if-a-number-is-written-in-square-brackets-like-5#comment95956240_54579404), essentially shorthand notation for `[_Global].Evaluate`, which ultimately resolves to `Application.Evaluate`... assuming we're not in a `Worksheet` module's code-behind, in which case it's shorthand for `Worksheet.Evaluate` - and both return a `Variant`, which means any chained member calls are blind, late-bound calls resolved at run-time: `Option Explicit` can't save you from a typo.

That's why [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) (an open-source VBIDE add-in project I manage / contribute to) resolves them as "runtime expressions":

[image: Rubberduck's context-sensitive toolbar showing 'A1' as a 'runtime expression']

In other words this:

```
Range("E16").Value = Mid(line, 49, [6])
```

Could just as well be written like this:

```
[E16] = Mid(line, [49], [6])
```

...which is arguably terrible code with a ton of redundant implicit operations going on.

There is never, *NEVER* any reason whatsoever to square-bracket an integer literal: it's nothing more than a rather roundabout way to turn an `Integer` literal into a `Double` (since worksheet numeric values are `Variant/Double`):

```
Debug.Print TypeName(42)
Integer

Debug.Print TypeName([42])
Double
```

Which is much better off done with an explicit conversion:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(CDbl(42))
Double
```

...or even with a (*gasp*) type hint:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(42#)
Double
```

Comment: Also note-worthy in Excel is the fact that `Application.Evaluate` returns a `Variant`, so it has a nasty little side effect of implicitly removing the strong typing. The other side effect is that the literal for the number is implicitly converted to a `String` before being passed to evaluate, so the number you end up with is dependent on locale settings.

Comment: This is very nitpicky but an implicit reference outside the worksheet's code-behind actually accesses `[_Global].Evaluate()`, not `Application.Evaluate()`. I'm sure it resolves to the same implementation but want to point this out because 1) that's yet another level of implicit operation and 2) it may lead to surprises when the `Evaluate()` in one context does X but in other context, does Y.

Comment: Small clarification; if `[blah]` is shorthand for `[_Global].Evaluate(blah)`, then why do we type `[E16]` to mean `.Evaluate("E16")` and not `["E16"]` with `"` speech marks. Does this work like [bang notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15958981/6609896) and always pass what's between brackets as a string literal? i.e. `[49]` is actually equivalent to `[_Global].Evaluate("49")`

Comment: @Greedo `Evaluate` takes a string argument, yes. But whether a bracketed expression translates to a call to the host application's `Evaluate` method depends on a number of things, including whether the host has such a method - lookup "foreign identifiers" in MS-VBAL language specs for more info about them.