# Get the value before the ubound each time

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, export-to-excel

```vb
Dim txt As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim reference As Variant
Dim d As Integer

d = Worksheets("Sheet1").cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
txt = cells(3, 4).Value
reference = Split(txt, " ")

For i = 0 To UBound(reference)
    cells(d + 1, [4]).Value = reference(i)
Next

txt = cells(3, 4).Value
reference = Split(txt, " ")
cells(d + 1, [12]).Value = reference(3)
```

Hi, im trying to pick the reference before the ubound value each time, and the copy to the reference to the last line. I got this code to work when its the 4th part of the string but im trying to always pick the value before the ubound. Is it possible to do UBOUND -1. or do i have to go another way around this. thanks max

Comment: `reference(UBound(reference)-1)`?

Comment: BigBen is right, it's as simple as that (and why not) - you only have to ensure that Ubound(a) > 0, else you will get a "Subscript out of Range" error

Comment: Just for curiosity: How did you get the idea to write `[4]` in square brackets - it's very uncommon (and superfluous), I had a question on SO some time ago about the meaning https://stackoverflow.com/q/54579404/7599798

Comment: Thanks BigBen and FunThomas for your responses, The [4] is the column index i know its quite uncommon but i unfortunately slipped in the habit.

Comment: Also thank you big ben that works great thank you

Comment: @MaxMurrell - so you are using `[]` because it reminds you of a column?

Comment: @MaxMurrell - Reading the question from @FunThomas, I see in the comments this - *[] can also be used when accessing a table's column, such as Range("Table[Col1]") – Mistella Feb 7 '19 at 18:13*. So, I understand why you are using it... But... On behalf on every VBA developer, who has "inherited" VBA code and had to understand what is written before rewriting it, please, stop using `[]` for the columns. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically 2 ways to pick the prelast value.

**Option 1** - Using `Ubound()`:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim reference As String
    reference = "Stack Overflow is my favourite VBA site!"
    
    Dim splitted As Variant
    splitted = Split(reference)
    
    Debug.Print splitted(UBound(splitted) - 1)
        
End Sub
```

**Option 2** - Using predefined function for array length and removing 2 from it:

Calling it this way:

```
Debug.Print splitted(GetArrayLength(splitted) - 2)
```

The function:

```
Private Function GetArrayLength(myArray As Variant) As Long
    
    If IsEmpty(myArray) Then
        GetArrayLength = 0
    Else
        GetArrayLength = UBound(myArray) - LBound(myArray) + 1
    End If
    
End Function
```

The function is a bit better, because it checks for empty arrays.

Comment: @MaxMurrell - you are welcome. Additionally, if you are going to split by one space, like this `reference = Split(txt, " ")`, you can shorten the code to this reference = Split(txt)`, VBA would get what you mean.