# How to create dynamic VBA for Access code which will build

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been successfully using code such as:

`Forms![MyForm]!Option1 = False`

However, I now wish to make the above dynamic by using N = 1,2,3,4 etc. So the new code would look something like:

`Forms![MyForm]!Option & N = True`

Does anyone have any hints about how to make this work?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to avoid using bang notation `!`. Instead, use fully qualified references like this:

```
Forms.Item("MyForm").Controls.Item("Option" & N).Value = True
```

If you want to know more about bang notation there are SO threads like this one about it:
[Bang Notation and Dot Notation in VBA and MS-Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923957/bang-notation-and-dot-notation-in-vba-and-ms-access)